# How to get Facebook friends list in using Spring Social

Tags: spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jhipster, spring-social

I am trying to get FB friends list. I know that it will return only those who also using the app.

I made REST point that should return friends list. Here is modified code for tests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fbfriends",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<User> GetFriends(Connection<?> connection) {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Friends");
    if (connection == null) {
        log.error("Cannot create social user because connection is null");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Connection cannot be null");
    }
    log.debug("Got connection");

    List<Permission> permissions = facebook.userOperations().getUserPermissions();
    log.debug("Permission size: " + permissions.size() + " Permission: " + permissions);
    for (Permission perm: permissions){
        log.debug(perm.getName() + " " + perm.getStatus());
    }

    List<User> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendProfiles();
    log.debug("Friends size: " + friends.size() + " Friends:" + friends.toString());

    PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
    log.debug("Feed size: " + feed.size() + " Feed: " + feed.toString());

    PagedList<UserTaggableFriend> taggable = facebook.friendOperations().getTaggableFriends();
    log.debug("Taggable size: " + friends.size() + " Taggable:" + friends.toString());

    log.debug("Ho Ho Ho");

    return friends;
}
```

All those `log.debug` just for me, here is the result:

```
2016-07-27 17:38:22.443 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection() with result = org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection@99deb877
2016-07-27 17:38:22.581 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : Permission size: 2 Permission: [org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Permission@8fbfe4, org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Permission@5328b7d2]
2016-07-27 17:38:22.581 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : email granted
2016-07-27 17:38:22.581 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : public_profile granted
2016-07-27 17:38:22.694 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : Friends size: 0 Friends:[]
2016-07-27 17:38:22.739 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : Feed size: 0 Feed: []
2016-07-27 17:38:22.788 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : Taggable size: 0 Taggable:[]
2016-07-27 17:38:22.789 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource      : Ho Ho Ho
2016-07-27 17:38:22.798 DEBUG 10828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest.FbFriendResource.GetFriends() with result = []
```

As you can see there is only two permissions granted: `public_profile` and `email`.

In some examples I found that permissions could be added:
[image]

I didn't found anything like this. In my App settings I found only this page under "App Review"

[image]

Here is `user_friends` "live and available for users"

1. What I did wrong or how to actually use this "granted by default" permission using Spring Social?
2. How can I ask for additional permissions like `user_posts` and use them in Spring Framework?

Comment: It will only return those friends who granted user_friends permission to the app. My guess is that you are not asking for it

Comment: I understand that it will return only those users. I have 3-4 users who used FB login in my app. As shown on 2nd screenshot there is `user_friends` in "approved items" but it doesn't return this permission through `facebook.userOperations().getUserPermissions()` method. I am asking how to use this permission (supposed to be granted by default) and ask/add new permissions.

Comment: You read the Facebook Login documentation on how to ask for permissions

Comment: My bad! I went through samples and some outdated manuals. Thought that permissions are defined at app settings or something like at the 1st screenshot. Thx for the direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was pretty simple. If someone has the same problems, permissions for the app defined in request to the FB at Facebook Login button.

Something like this depends on your case.

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Was new to this and just used sample code for login button without review and thoght that permissions defined at App settings.

Comment: please help getting blank no photo. tried to add in link but no benefit only users who has authorised photo is coming my page http://way2enjoy.com/facebook-fun

Comment: plz help if you canhelp